# Track a moving paper with some patterns

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'd like to track movement of a paper that has a pattern on it (let's say a checkerboard pattern).

Will I have to use that Haar-like Cascade thing or is there an easier way for detecting a relatively simple thing like this?

I am using EmguCV with C#.

Comment: use a QR-Code as a pattern and a QR-Code detector (there are some findable by google).

Comment: Hmm, thats a good idea actually..

Comment: if you can solve it this way, please write an answer yourself and the used libraries etc :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to track just a simple pattern (like checkerboard) there is definitely a better solution than Haar.

I don't have experience with OpenCV for .NET but you should look into the built-in function [findChessboardCorners](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga93efa9b0aa890de240ca32b11253dd4a) or if you need a bit faster tracking with orientation as well you should check [ArUco marker detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d6d/tutorial_table_of_content_aruco.html) that exist as a contrib module.